# Typescript Redux No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

i am fairly new to typescript, but i thought i can use it with react and redux for one of my side project.Everthing was working fine , until i come to the part where i need to use reducers.
So followingis my reducer code.

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../actions/types';

export interface FetchVideo {
  isLoading: boolean;
  allVideos: ReadonlyArray<string[]>;
  errorFetching: string;
}

const intialState: FetchVideo = {
  isLoading: false,
  allVideos: [],
  errorFetching: '',
};

type FetchVideoAction = {
  type: ActionTypes;
  payload: FetchVideo;
};

export const videoReducer = (state = intialState, action: FetchVideoAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_DATA_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        errorFetching: '',
      };
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        allVideos: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: '',
      };
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: action.payload,
      };
    default:return state

  }
};
```

Now, what i did is make a Store State interface and pass it as a genric to combineReducer, like the following

```
export interfac      profile: ProfileDet;e StoreState {
  sideBar: ToggleActionDetails;
  fetchVideo: FetchVideo;
}

export const reducers = combineReducers<StoreState>({
  sideBar: sideBarReduer,
  fetchVideo: videoReducer,
});
```

Now i am getting an error saying this,

[image]

From my understanding, the spread operator is making things go wrong.I even used Null operator to handle the undefined issue.But still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS` branch of your switch case. It has

```js
case ActionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        allVideos: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: '',
      };
```

The type of `allVideos` is defined in `FetchVideo` as `ReadonlyArray<string[]>`, but you are trying to assign `action.payload` to it which has the type `FetchVideo` as defined in `FetchVideoAction`. That's the issue - you can't assign an object of type `FetchVideo` to a `ReadonlyArray<string[]>`.

In fact, the error message does hint to this: see the last line above the stacktrace: (`Type ... is not assignable to type 'FetchVideo'`). Agreed, it didn't give a very helpful line number, but it does indicate that there's a trivial type mismatch somewhere.